# Pop up window - once on load and every 3 months after using Javascript Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, popupwindow

I wondered if anyone maybe able to help?

I have managed to create a pop open window script with a time delay. I need it to open on the first visit and not again for three months.

I am completely lost and have trawled the internet all day today and most of yesterday. I am new to Javascript and Cookies.

Thank you in advance. Saul

Here is the script for the pop open window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start(theURL, winName,w,h) {
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
var targetWin = window.open (theURL, winName, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 
setTimeout(start, 1*1000, 'pop_up.html', 'pop-up-title',200,100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my way and its very rough but when the page loads I would see if a cookie exists  for example my cookie is called CookieDisplay. Check it with:

```
 var mycookie= getCookie("CookieDisplay");
        if (mycookie== null ){

            start();
        }


function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

if the page has been loaded and the cookie exists then don't load the window. If the cookie doesn't exist then run your start() function. Somewhere within the start() function create the cookieDisplay cookie  so next round trip, when the page loads a check is made, the cookie is found and the window doesn't open The set cookie example is here:

```
 function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" +                 exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Beware if you're in the EU though regarding the new cookie law.

Comment: you could probably add the javascript to the script tag you have already and then call the function on the body load for example <body onload="setandCheckCookie()">. The setandCheckCookie() would hold the code that I mentioned above that started with var mycookie =getCookie("CookieDisplay")

Comment: http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx  will help you with the new cookie law

Comment: I've written the script as I think it may be intended but it's not allowing me to post it. Seems nothing really wants to go in my favour today! :-/

Comment: Most if its there for you, you just need to adjust a few lines here and there for your logic.  setCookie("CookieDisplay", true, 90);   would add it for roughly three months give and take a couple of days

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid my head is just completely spun out looking at this stuff for 2 days now. I can kind of understand whats going on but not enough to edit it and get it to do as I want. Thank you for your help anyway though.